# Pip install fontforge, says Couldnot find a version

Tags: pip, fontforge

I have done, `apt-get install fontforge` on my ubuntu system. When i do `import fontforge` in my python code, it throws error as, `No module named fontforge`.

When i do, `pip install fontforge`, it throws error as,,

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fontforge (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fontforge
```

How can i install fontforge's python libs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to install `python3-fontforge`.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-fontforge
```

After that you should be able to use `fontforge` in ubuntu's python version 3.

You can verify by doing `/usr/bin/python3 -c "import fontforge;print(fontforge)"`. This should now print the path to the `fontforge` python module.